# Continuity argument to show that the derivative exists everywhere.

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, derivatives, continuity

I have shown that, for $f(X) = \det(X)$,

$$\mathrm d f_A(H) = \mathrm{tr} (\mathrm{adj}(A) H)$$

But I have only show this for invertible $A$. I wish to use a continuity argument to show that this formula holds for all $A$.

Does the following argument work?

Let $A$ be an arbitrary matrix. For any $\delta > 0$ there is some intvertible matrix $A'$ such that $\lVert A - A'\rVert < \delta$ (proof withheld).

Because $\mathrm df_A(H)$ is continuous, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is some $\delta > 0$ such that $$\lVert{A - A'}\rVert < \delta \implies \lvert \mathrm df_A(H) - \mathrm df_A'(H)\rvert < \epsilon$$

I am trying to say that, because invertible matrices are dense in the space of matrices and because the derivative is continuous, the derivative must exist for non-invertible matrices and the formula must hold for them but I am not sure how to wrap my argument up.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the right idea. Take $A'$ so that also $|\mathrm{tr}(\mathrm{adj}(A) H)-\mathrm{tr}(\mathrm{adj}(A') H)|<\epsilon$. Then $$|df_A(H)-\mathrm{tr}(\mathrm{adj}(A) H)|=$$$$|df_A(H)+df_{A'}H-df_{A'}H+\mathrm{tr}(\mathrm{adj}(A') H)-\mathrm{tr}(\mathrm{adj}(A') H)-\mathrm{tr}(\mathrm{adj}(A) H)|\leq $$$$|df_{A}H-df_A(H)|+|df_{A'}H-\mathrm{tr}(\mathrm{adj}(A') H)|+|\mathrm{tr}(\mathrm{adj}(A') H)-\mathrm{tr}(\mathrm{adj}(A) H)|\leq 2\epsilon$$